# what is the minimal gui system in linux to run Electron

Tags: linux, user-interface, electron

I have a CentOS 8 server running without GUI. Now i want to run an Electron app on it, full screen on start, but i don't want to install KDE or GNOME, they are too big.

So what should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please refer [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150493/is-it-possible-to-install-firefox-on-ubuntu-with-no-desktop-enviroment)

to run any GUI application you at least need xorg. Desktop environments are not required. so after installing try:

```
startx
your-appllication
```

to enter in full screen mode set browserwindows [fullscreen](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) to true

Also note that you cant move or resize window. likewise you have to explicitly provide functionality for closing the application